# Getting realtime weather data charted using python and google apps script

Tags: python, google-apps-script, synchronization, fifo

Apologies if too stupid question:

I run the weather data logging program Cumulus on my pc. It writes each data sample to the realtime.txt file every second (the previous sample is always overwritten i.e. file size stays at 1 data row).

I want to publish a pseudo-realtime chart of the last hour of wind data (strength and direction) to the web. My plan is to have a Python program reading the realtime.txt data rows each second and append them to a buffer which is saved to a file. A Google App script is then time-triggered every minute, reads the buffer file and appends the last minute's worth of data to a circular one-hour data table in Google Sheets. The table's data is used in a line chart, which is then published and can be read by anyone.

So basically I have a short term (1-minute) FIFO which feeds a longer term (1-hour) FIFO using a buffer file for transfer.

Now my problem is how to sync these FIFOs so that every one-second data row is counted, and no rows are counted twice. As the two apps are unsynchronized, this is not trivial at least not for me.

I'm thinking of giving each data row a unique row number, enabling the App script to figure out where to put the next chunk of data in the longer term buffer. Also to expand the short term FIFO to 2 minutes, which would ensure that there is always at least 1-minutes worth of fresh data available regardless of any jitter in the trigger time of the App script.

But converting these thoughts into code is proving a bit overwhelming for me ;( Anyone had the same problem or can otherwise advise, even slightly?

Comment: The basic idea here is that you create a script and run into a problem and you come here and show us your script and possibly your spreadsheet and we try to help you with your problem. [mcve]

Comment: Can you get your data logging program to append data to a file?

Comment: Unfortunately not, Cooper. The realtime.txt file always contains just the most recent data row. That's why I need the Python program maintaining the short term buffer.